# App disappeared from developer account

Tags: facebook

After adding a test user, my app disappeared from my list in the developer account. I can still access the app:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/337746716318749
but it is gone from my settings.

Comment: Did you add your self as tester? You can only have one role on the app. So it means you moved yourself from admin/developer to tester. Tell one of the other admins to add you back as admin

Comment: Yep ... thats what I did ... is there a way to undo this? How do I reach the other admins?

Comment: Were you the only admin on the app? If so file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs . If not ask one of the other admins on the app to add you back